# given argument values are changed in the function body in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I have following header and function definition;

blautil.hpp

```
namespace blautil{
    ...
    cv::Mat compute_mean_mat(std::vector<cv::Mat> data, const int w, const int h);
    ...
}
```

blautil.cpp

```
namespace blautil{
...
    cv::Mat compute_mean_mat(std::vector<cv::Mat> data, const int w, const int h){
        cv::Mat Mean = cv::Mat::zeros(w, h, CV_32F);
        for (int i = 1; i <= data.size(); i++){
            cv::Mat image = data[i];
            Mean += image;
        }
        Mean = Mean / data.size();
        Mean.convertTo(Mean, CV_8U);
        return Mean;
    }
...
}
```

I call it like here;

```
cv::Mat mean_img = blautils::compute_mean_mat(imageVector, width, height);
```

The problem is in the runtime these width and height values are 25 and 45 respectively but when code enters into the function body they are changes into different random large values.

I am coding at VS2013 Win8. From these pbservations, what would you suggest to diagnose that interesting problem ?

Edit:
Once I defined default values for w and h before and after one compilation I removed. This problem occurred after there. Same problem also appeared at another function as well, I solved it by changing the order of the function parameters but for now it does not work as well

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i <= data.size(); i++){`  You are going out of bounds on the last iteration.

Comment: Just to be sure, cv::Mat::zeros passes its two parameters by value, not by reference.  It's not the zeroes function that's changing them, right?  Also, you should avoid copying your entire array by value; consider "const std::vector<cv::Mat> &data" so that the entire array is not copied but only a pointer to the array is passed to the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When parameters are overwritten it probably means you are writing over the boundaries of the stack. I don't know if it's causing the actual problem, but you're trying to access an invalid element of data, since i can become data.size(). The loop should be

```
for (int i = 1; i <= data.size(); i++){
...
}
```

To analyse this specific problem, printf or cout the value of i together with the values of w and h and you should be able to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: yeag I see what you mean. It was an copy paste code and I realized by your call like the above one

Answer (score 0):

One error right away that I see is this one:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= data.size(); i++)
                  ^^
{
    cv::Mat image = data[i];
    Mean += image;
}
```

It should be:

```
for (int i = 1; i < data.size(); i++)
```

Much safer, where you don't go out of bounds:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), [&](cv::Mat& m){Mean += m;});
```

Comment: how about using `for(auto & e : data) Mean += e;` instead of `std::for_each()`

Comment: Yes, but that darn VS 2013 didn't implement all of C++ 11.  They got most of the lambda stuff ok, but not sure if `auto` works fully  (it does, but can't know for sure).

Comment: this is copy paste code, I realized by your call :)